# how to show a data set satisfying a equation?

Tags: interpolation

I have a set of data points like $(1,6)$, $(4,9)$, etc., and I am given a specific linear equation with two variable like $y = a/b + b x$. How can I show that the data points fit the curve?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe you can use [Linear least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

As said by Voliar, this problem is relevant from linear least squares provided that you rewrite the model as $$y=c+b x$$ Compute $b$ and $c$ and later make $a=b c$. Writen as $$y = \frac {a} {b} + b x$$ the model is not linear with respect to its parameters.

I suppose that this was the trap.

With regard to the question about showing that the data points fit the curve, put on the same plot the graph the function as well as the individual data points used for the regression.